# Inequality involving powers of factorials

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

I need help for proving inequality

$$((k+1)!)^{k+1}.(2k+3)! \geq ((k+2)!)^{k+2} $$

for any $k \geq 0$.

I have attached my attempt.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is almost complete! From your last line we have
$$(2k+3)!\geq (k+2)^{k+1}(k+2)!$$
Thus, by dividing both sides by $(k+2)!$, we obtain the equivalent inequality
$$(2k+3)(2k+2)\cdots(k+3)=\prod_{j=1}^{k+1}(k+2+j)\geq (k+2)^{k+1}$$
which is true because each factor on the left, $(k+2+j)$, is greater than $(k+2)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm confused however how dividing by (k+2)! by both sides we obtain the inequality you listed above.

Comment: The lhs is $(2k+3)!$.The rhs is $(k+2)^{k+1}(k+2)! $

Comment: I get the right side.  I just don't understand how dividing by (k+2)! we obtain (2k+3)(2k+2)....(k+3)=multiplied (k+2+j) multiplied from j=1 to k+1.

Comment: like where does the k+3 come from and how does that explicitly equal to the product (k+2+j) from j=1 to k+1.  Thanks.

Comment: @kemb $(2k+3)!/(k+2)!$ is the product of all integers from $(k+3)$ to $(2k+3)$ that is $\prod_{j=1}^{k+1}(k+2+j)$. Recall the definition of the factorial.

Comment: is there  a way to explicitly show to help me out that (2k+3)!/(k+2)!=(2k+3)(2k+2)..(k+3).  Thanks,(you've been very  helpful).

Comment: @kemb Note that $(2k+3)!=(2k+3)\cdots (k+3)(k+2)\cdots 2\cdot 1$ and $(k+2)!=(k+2)\cdots 2\cdot 1$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, it is clear.

Answer (score 2):

$$((k+1)!)^{k+1}(2k+3)!\geq((k+2)!)^{k+2}.$$

On the RHS, $((k+2)!)^{k+2}=(k+2)^{k+2}((k+1)!)^{k+2}.$

This gives:

$$(2k+3)!\geq (k+2)^{k+2}(k+1)!.$$

Next,

$$\frac{(2k+3)!}{(k+1)!}=(2k+3)\cdot(2k+2)\cdots (k+2).$$

There are a total of $2k+3-(k+2)+1=k+2$ terms on the r.h.s.

Thus,

$$\frac{(2k+3)!}{(k+1)!}\geq (k+2)^{k+2},$$

which completes the proof.